# Is there a way to save a PHP session for a specific path?

Tags: php, session

I have 2 directories on a site, dir1 and dir2, and I need it to do this: When the script writes the session from dir1, it cannot be read from dir2. Is that possible?
I tried `session_set_cookie_params(0,'/dir1/')`, but anyway you can access this session var from dir2.

Comment: try `session_save_path()`

Comment: Do you call `session_set_cookie_param` before `session_start`?

Comment: You should look if your hosting allows to define those settings on a per-directory basis – so that you don’t have to go through that every time a script gets called in coding.

Comment: imho the best thing would be to roll your own session save handler the takes into account the request path before deserializing the session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually done via namespaces. You should assign session namespace (simple string identifier) to your requests and then provide some wrapper for accessing your session based on this namespace.

What is a session namespace? Just a session attribute which holds associative array, which then acts as your session. Your session will look like this:

```
$_SESSION (
    "DIR1_NAMESPACE" => array(),
    "DIR2_NAMESPACE" => array(),
)
```

Modern PHP frameworks usually support session namespacing (e.g. http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.session.container.html).

So in the end you don't need to store completely separated sessions. You just split the existing session into multiple storages.

Comment: thank you very much! I just used session_name('DIR1') and all works properly.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION` is global var, I am not sure if it's possible to control the availablity for specific directory, but may be a little idea:

```
if( __DIR__ === 'dir2' )
{
   unset($_SESSION['from']['dir1']);
}
```